# MemoryError when trying to load 5GB text file

Tags: python, file, out-of-memory, text-files, large-data

I want to read data stored in text format in a 5GB file. when I try to read the content of file using this code:

```
file = open('../data/entries_en.txt', 'r')
data = file.readlines()
```

an error occurred:
    data = file.readlines()
    MemoryError
My laptop has 8GB memory and at least 4GB is empty when I want to run the program. but when I monitor the system performance, when python uses about 1.5GB of memory, this error happens.
I'm using python 2.7, but if it matters please tell me solution for 2.x and 3.x
What should I do to read this file?

Comment: Python version? Also, why are you reading it all at once? Finally, if you *really* want to do that, `list(file)` is more modern and "idiomatic".

Comment: What OS? 64-bit? or 32-bit? Is Python compiled as a 64-bit or a 32-bit binary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way for you to handle large files would be -

```
with open('../file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        # do stuff
```

`readlines()` would error because you are trying to load too large a file directly into the memory. The above code will automatically close your file once you are done processing on it.

Comment: what if I have 100 gb RAM and want to do `readlines()`. Will it still not work? Any workaround this?

Comment: The depends on your operating system - not all operating systems will give you full access to all the moemory for every process. I believe that a 32bit O/S is restricted to 4GB per process. Processing per line - or per "chunk" is likely to be much more effective.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to process lines in the file, you should rather use:

```
for line in file:
    # do something with the line
```

It will read the file line by line, instead of reading it all to the RAM at once.